# Graph call Error When Getting User Page Information (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm having some trouble making some graph calls with Koala.

Graph calls:

```
        @graph_data = @api.get_object("me/books")
        @account_data = @api.get_connections("me","accounts")
```

I have a do loop in my callback.html.erb that shows a table which displays the name of the user's favorite books.

(had to remove the html tags)

```
@graph.data.each do |data|
  data["name"]
end
```

This code is fine, i get a table with all the book names.

The problem occurs when i want to display the @account_data object, this is supposed to hold the information of all the pages the user is an admin of.

I am expecting a table with the names of all the pages the user is subscribed to.
@account_data should have exactly two array elements since i am admin for two pages.

My understanding is that i should be getting an object that looks like this:

```
[{field1=>val1,field2=>val2,....}, {field1=>val1,field2=>val2,....}]
```

I tried using the Graph call @api.get_object("me/accounts") but same problem - blank screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the permissions set to access that?

Comment: i've set permissions for "manage_pages" on the dashboard.